# How to draw an historical frieze in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an json object like that :

```
{
"data":{
"2012-12-29":[
    {"Dir":112.5,"Spd":2,"Spl":7,"Max":16},
    {...}
    {"Dir":"null","Spd":0,"Spl":1,"Max":null}
],
"2012-12-20":[
    {"Dir":22.5,"Spd":2,"Spl":7,"Max":16},
    {...}
    {"Dir":"null","Spd":0,"Spl":1,"Max":null}
],
"2012-12-31":[
    {"Dir":90,"Spd":2,"Spl":7,"Max":16},
    {...}
    {"Dir":"null","Spd":0,"Spl":1,"Max":null}
],
...
}
```

I would like draw each DATE on a X axis represented each DATE by a circle.
the Y valus is always : 0, all circle are on the X axes.

After I include `D3.on("click",function (){...})` on each circle to show inner data.

In first step I make an array of DATE only:

```
var list=[];
for (var keydate in DATA) {
    list.push(keydate);
    i++;
}
```

after I would like draw my DATE but I do not know how to?

```
var svg = d3.select(container)
    .append("svg")

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(list)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
```

Comment: Can you please post your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: At the very least you will want to set the cx and cy [attributes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-attr) of your circles, probably right after you append them. You may also want to use a [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-scale) to figure out the correct cx attribute. You could then also use an [axis](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-axis) to draw your dates for you.